# Eclipse debugger does not stop in anonymous class?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I put a breakpoint within an anonymous class which does indeed get executed (I see a print statement i added output to console). But it does not break at, for example, the print. Is this expected and is there a way to get the break to happen?

Answer (score 0):

debugger works with anonymous classes, that's for sure. issue must be somewhere else:

1. are you sure application is started in debug mode?
2. if it's a remote application, are you sure your debugger is connected to it?
3. are you sure what is being executed matches source code you are watching?

If yes to everything, please reduce application to minimum reproducible issue and paste here.

Comment: ok why the downvotes? at least any comment to know why? requester asked if this can be debugged on eclipse and the answer was given: yes. in regards to finding why he cannot: given the input that's the more concrete answer that can be given

Comment: why do you think OP (me) would not know to run the code in debug -- your suggestions, all of them, are obvious.

Comment: i added them for completeness. you did a question and i answered: eclipse can debug anonymous classes. 3rd option may not be so obvious, this happens to many people. Also you didn't paste the minimum reproducible code i asked for. Paste it and i will be able to help you maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question. If I'm right, **your code must be something like this**:

```
1. JButton myButton = new JButton("My button");
2. myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
3.    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
4.      System.out.println("Action performed on my button");
5.     }
6. });
```

*You have to put your breakpoint on line 4. If you put it on line 2, it will be triggered when the action listener is initialized. If you put it on line 3, it will never be triggered. At line 4, it will be triggered when you press the button.
I've tested this a few minutes ago using Eclipse debugger.*
**Did you put your breakpoint at your "System.out.println" line? It should work.**

[Click here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/I_put_a_breakpoint_in_anonymous_inner_class_When_I_debug_the_program_doesnt_notice_the_break_point_How_should_solve_it)  to see full details